# Is formation of cyclic carbonate from trimethyl orthoformate and vicinal aromatic 1,2-diol possible?

Tags: synthesis, carbonyl-compounds, alcohols, phenols, protecting-groups

[image]

Hello, my question is, "is it possible cyclic carbonate formation between trimethyl orthoformate and  vicinal aromatic 1,2-diol"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Trimethyl orthoformate is at the wrong oxidation level to give a cyclic carbonate. You need phosgene or a dialkyl carbonate. The efficient preparation of catechol carbonate from catechol (benzene-1,2-diol) and dimethyl carbonate is described in this [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/323752125_Process_Systems_for_the_Carbonate_Interchange_Reactions_of_DMC_and_Alcohols_Efficient_synthesis_of_Catechol_Carbonate)